# How to convert arguments list to string of each on new line in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I want to get list to :var into `emacs-lisp` code block in Emacs Org-mode and to output just each of list item on new line. In `ruby` it looks as simple as

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ruby 
[1,2,3,4]*"\n"
#+END_SRC
```

But cannot realise how to do it in Emacs lisp code block.

Comment: I believe you're talking about org-babel. Could you update the question with the actual org syntax, so it's clearer what you are asking? It sounds like you have a working ruby example, so if you post that (as a minimal org file), people can see what you are trying to replicate.

Comment: @phils I've corrected the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(mapconcat #'number-to-string '(1 2 3 4) "\n")
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 1
: 2
: 3
: 4
```